# Oracle create operator

Tags: oracle, syntax, oracle11g

I've recently run into a case where a fuzzy-match was useful when categorizing historical unstructured-string data.  UTL_MATCH is great and has worked well when wrapping into a truthy fuzzy-match function.  But I wanted to be joining ad-hoc, and took the route of building out a new function-based operator.

OPERATOR creation: (function-based,  FUZZY_MATCH returns 0 for unmatched, 1 for match.  A dummy version is included here)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUZZY_MATCH(
  LEFT_ITEM  VARCHAR2,
  RIGHT_ITEM VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER AS BEGIN
  RETURN 1;
END;



CREATE OR REPLACE OPERATOR RESEMBLES
  BINDING (VARCHAR2, VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER USING FUZZY_MATCH
;
```

Creating a new operator works fine, but I've been a little dissatisfied with the resultant sql syntax (example below).

```
CREATE TABLE LEFT_TABLE(ARBITRARY_DATA VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE RIGHT_TABLE(ARBITRARY_DATA VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO LEFT_TABLE VALUES ('In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.');
INSERT INTO RIGHT_TABLE VALUES ('In the ground there lived a hobbit.');

SELECT
  LEFT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA LEFT_DATA,
  RIGHT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA RIGHT_DATA
FROM
  LEFT_TABLE
  INNER JOIN
  RIGHT_TABLE
       ON 1 = RESEMBLES ( LEFT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA, RIGHT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA )
;
```

Is there an alternative OPERATOR definition to make the truthiness of the operator implicit, allowing for more natural syntax like the following? I'm on 11gR2

Thanks

```
SELECT
  LEFT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA LEFT_DATA,
  RIGHT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA RIGHT_DATA
FROM
  LEFT_TABLE
  INNER JOIN
  RIGHT_TABLE
  ON LEFT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA RESEMBLES RIGHT_TABLE.ARBITRARY_DATA;
```